# Graph Database for Users

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, relational-database

In my application, I need users to be assigned to groups, and each user to have  a manager (the manager, who is also a user, may have a manager as well).

The app will require queries to know the maximum depth of a certain manager (so, in other words, the length of the longest path starting from a manager down to all people managed by that person). Additionally, it will need to be able to find users who are in the same group (a group can also be a member of another group).

To this point, the entire application had been modeled with JPA in a MySQL database. However, it is designed as an SOA, so changing the underlying data store of the service that handles users (user-service) wouldn't be all that expensive.

Are there any ways of doing this that don't require a graph database? If a graph database is necessary, should I store *all* user information in the graph, or just the appropriate relationships?

Comment: What do you mean by a "graph database"? You can certainly map groups as a category table, and the relationships as a many-to-many table. I don't see a need for a separate database.

Answer (score 2):

If your basic model is

```
(group:Group)<-[:IN_GROUP]-(user:User)
(man:User)-[:MANAGES]->(sub:User)
```

you can do:

```
MATCH (manager:User {name:"Colin"})-[:MANAGES*]->(u:User)
RETURN u
```

for your second query

```
MATCH (manager:User {name:"Colin"})-[:MANAGES*]->(u:User)
      (u)-[:IN_GROUP]->(g)<-[:IN_GROUP]-(u2)
RETURN u.name as user, g.name as group, collect(u2.name) as colleagues
```

You can store all user information in the graph but you don't have to. Do what's easiest for your and best for your use-case.

Without a graph database you're up to write painful heavy-JOIN SQL queries, esp. for the variable length relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the response - what do you think the performance would be like for finding all edge nodes (with variable length directed paths) from a base user? And also for counting the length of the longest path?